# Python doesn't run on Windows with a fatal error

Tags: python, window, fatal-error

In the command line in Windows, when i try to open a Python file using `python filename.py` i get this error and then python.exe crashes.

```
fatal python error py_initialize can't initialize sys standard streams
ImportError: no module named encodings_utf8
```

**Note**: I'm using Python 2.7

I have no idea what should i do.

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: Python 2.7, i'll add it to the question. Thanks.

Comment: Does this help: http://superuser.com/questions/223556/can-not-make-work-python-in-windows-7-64-bits

Comment: Hmm, the answer didn't clarify it that much unfortunately. How can i add to the Environment variables and what to add?

Comment: Try uninstalling and reinstalling python

Answer (score -2):

I think you should use pypy from http://pypy.org/download.html
don't forget to install that http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5582 before launching pypy :)
Of course try to uninstall python before and redownload it and reinstall it its maybe a download error
google md5 sum to check if downloads are corrupted
Also you didn't tell us which version of windows you are runnning